# Fisher exact test does not give expected results in R

Tags: r

I want to test if counts of A are greater than counts of B. I'm trying to use the fisher exact test but it gives me different results depending on how do I arrange the data. I dont know if the problem comes from this particular dataset (too many zeros) or if it comes from the way they are arranged.

First, i tried constructing a contingency table (m) as explained in the internet.

```
       factor
 counts     A       B
      0   205       226
      1    33        29
      2    15        18
      3    13         8
      4     4         2
      5     5         1
      6     3         0
      7     2         0
      9     1         0
      12    2         0
      23    1         0

fisher.test(m, workspace = 200000, hybrid = FALSE,
control = list(), or = 1, 
alternative = "two.sided",
conf.int = TRUE, 
conf.level = 0.95,
simulate.p.value = T, B = 2000)    
#results: data:  m  pvalue = 0.1184    alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

This gives me insignificant differences, which is totally unexpected when looking at the data and table. The dataset is too big and complicated to post here or simulate, but i can send it to anyone interested.

However, if i create a matrix of the contingency table...

```
classes=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,12,23)
A=c(205,33,15,13,4,5,3,2,1,2,1)
B=c(226,29,18,8,2,1,0,0,0,0,0)
m=as.matrix(data.frame(classes,A,B))
fisher.test(m, workspace = 200000, hybrid = FALSE,
control = list(), or = 1, 
alternative = "two.sided",
conf.int = TRUE, 
conf.level = 0.95,
simulate.p.value = T, B = 2000)
#results: data:  m p-value = 0.0004998 alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Which would be the correct procedure?  if its the first, how is that possible that such big differences are not significant??

Thanks

Comment: You don't have big differences in your first example. I'm not sure why you think it would be significant. E.g. - look at the column percentages within each group of `m` - `round(prop.table(m,2)*100,1)` - no big proportional differences there. Your second test of `m` is entirely different as it is also analysing the first `counts` column. You'll see you get comparable results if you do `fisher.test(m[,-1])` using the second example, but dropping the `counts` column.

Comment: Wrong forum (and not really about R) : Belongs on CV.com

Comment: @BondedDust - it's a bit of both - the reason why one result is significant and one is not is because of the interpretation of a table (2 columns + rownames), versus a matrix (3 columns) by `fisher.test`.

Comment: I suppose the confustion about R structures could use a discussion but the real error here is using the wrong test and expecting it to give the "right" answer. The 'counts'-column in the contingency table are not used at all in the fisher test, so the fact that the tail is much longer in category A is not being properly accounted for by `fisher.test`. I ended up deciding to give this an upvote because it may be useful in the long run to expose this deficiency of "homogeneity" tests.

Comment: @BondedDust - I agree with all you say. I'm really not sure what the 'counts' column represents in this instance, but it could have a huge impact on the distribution of responses. In the absence of such clarification, I'll leave this be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first item may well be an R contingency table (which is really a matrix in disguise) so that first "column" is actually a bunch of rownames. When I make a data.frame with those rownames and coerce to a matrix and pass to `fisher.test` I get the same result, as when I make a matrix ... without the extra column:

```
m=matrix( cbind(A,B),,2)
rownames(m)=classes

> m
   [,1] [,2]
0   205  226
1    33   29
2    15   18
3    13    8
4     4    2
5     5    1
6     3    0
7     2    0
9     1    0
12    2    0
23    1    0

> as.matrix(d)
     A   B
0  205 226
1   33  29
2   15  18
3   13   8
4    4   2
5    5   1
6    3   0
7    2   0
9    1   0
12   2   0
23   1   0
> fisher.test( as.matrix(d) )

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  as.matrix(d)
p-value = 0.1197
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

> fisher.test(m)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  m
p-value = 0.1197
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Please clarify your statistical (mis?)-understanding on this matter with your professor or the folks at CV.com. The minor numerical difference between your p-value and the two ones I showed is because you insisted on the "real" exact test in the first instance. Part of the loss of power to detect what we both suspect should be a statistically significant difference was the long tail of those distributions with small numbers. It gets handled improperly by the fisher.test. Furthermore the statistical power is diminished by the extra degrees of freedom. You would get more power by testing this as two exponential variates .... but that, too, is a matter for statistical discussion.

Comment: Many thanks to all and specially to BondedDust. Your example clarified me completely on the reason for different results. Those counts are abundance data, and they commonly come with a lot of zeroes and low values. The fact that species in A group reach consistently higher values at similar classes above zero is what indicates me that there is a clear difference. It means you consistently found more of type A when you went to the field. Fishers'test comes as an appropriate solution for comparing two distributions of count data, thats why i used it.

Comment: I hope it obvious that I vehemently  disagree that there is any generality to the statement: "Fisher's test comes as an appropriate solution for comparing two distributions of count data".